# Can variables be passed inside arguments in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, curl

My script deals with browser automation using cURL. I need to POST user input *username*. I can do this by hard-coding the *username* like this:

```sh
# sid -> session Id
# eid -> element Id (input box here)

curl -d '{"value":["username"]}' http://localhost:9515/session/$sid/element/$eid/value
```

This successfully posts *username* but I want to `read` username from user and pass this to *value*.

I tried:

```sh
read userName
curl -d '{"value":[$userName]}' http://localhost:9515/session/$sid/element/$eid/value
```

This gives me "missing command parameter" error. Passing only `$userName` instead of `[$userName]` gives "invalid argument: 'value' must be a list"

How do I pass a variable (userName) to the curl POST request in this case?

Comment: (1) The single quotes block parameter expansion to occur; and (2) Why do you now have brackets around your user name, and in the original version of the command you didn't?

Comment: @user1934428, I don't get what you are saying in (1). I've made the changes as pointed out in (2). Thanks.

Comment: If you have single quotes, no parameter expansion occurs inside. Hence, `' ... $userName'` does not expand `userName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've tried to use the variable within single quotes. Try to use double quotes instead:

```sh
read userName
curl -d "{\"value\":\"${userName}\"}" http://localhost:9515/session/$sid/element/$eid/value
```

Explanation:

> Single quotes (' ') operate similarly to double quotes, but do not permit referencing variables, since the special meaning of $ is turned off. Within single quotes, every special character except ' gets interpreted literally. Consider single quotes ("full quoting") to be a stricter method of quoting than double quotes ("partial quoting").

Taken from: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html

Comment: The ABS is a dubious reference; there are many better resources with fewer content problems.